# MySQL can't replace new line characters

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, newline, mariadb

I try to remove new line symbols from text type field, statement I use - below, tried all statements I found here with no luck:

```
UPDATE `ae1_jshopping_products`
SET `short_description_lt-LT` = REPLACE(`short_description_lt-LT`, '\r\n', ' ');
```

[image: Print of it]

I also attach print with error messages.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is not in the statement you posted. It seems you're trying to execute more than one statement and mixing the two (or more).

Comment: like fancyPants already mentioned - you are executing a different statement than you have posted. you can already see a part of the statement on the screenshot you have posted. please provide the actual statement - because there is no problem with the example statement you have posted.

Comment: I just go to phpMyAdmin and try to run exactly this statement: UPDATE `ae1_jshopping_products` SET `short_description_lt-LT` = REPLACE(`short_description_lt-LT`, '\r\n',' '); and get errors exactly as in print screen + when i run statement "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

Comment: please put your exact statement in your question - because that's where the problem is at!

Answer (score 0):

put your fieldname `short_description_lt-LT` into backticks:

```
UPDATE `ae1_jshopping_products` 
SET `short_description_lt-LT` = REPLACE(`short_description_lt-LT`, '\r\n',' ');
```

**explanation:** MySQL can't know if you want to subtract `LT` FROM `short_description_lt`  or if `-` belongs to your fieldname.

Comment: But it looks exactly as you say, please check first print screen of my query, it uses backticks `short_description_lt-LT`: SET `short_description_lt-LT` = REPLACE(`short_description_lt-LT`, '\r\n', ' '); Here it is formatted but i use  ` symbol

Comment: @NoOne yeah, I know - but you changed the code in your question a couple of times - so this answer was for the version without backticks `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps there is a hidden character that may be causing the problem.

[image: Statement]

[image: Executed statement]

Using:

- MariaDB: 10.0.22
- phpMyAdmin: 4.6.0

Comment: It makes no sense :( Copied from Notepad as is... Could it be the problem of phpMyAdmin? As i use XAMPP on localhost with latest version: Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB and PHP version: 5.6.19

Comment: phpMyAdmin is : 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Your outdated phpMyAdmin version is affected by a bug with the SQL parsing library where it thinks your statement is incorrect. You should be able to solve it by upgrading to a more recent version (4.6.1 is expected to be released within a week).

Comment: Thank you, i'll check it then.